# Which statement is true concerning digital signature?

Tags: signature

Which statement is true concerning digital signature?

1. can be used as a cryptosystem and signature system.
2. a way of encrypting confidential data
3. a method of sending handwritten signature to digital media
4. allows the receiver of data to prove the source and integrity

Comment: This looks like homework. What have you tried, can you rule out some options, what do you not understand?

Comment: @otus: Actually, it looks more like a take-home or online exam question to me. Normal homework, at least IME, is rarely multiple-choice. Still not good question for Stack Exchange, IMO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a [dump of a homework (or exam) question with no effort shown](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1115/do-we-want-to-update-the-way-we-handle-homework-questions)

Answer (score 3):

> Which statement is true concerning digital signature?
>
> 1. can be used as a cryptosystem and signature system.

No. A cryptosystem is generally a system where confidentiality, integrity and authenticity can be achieved.

So a cryptosystem will likely also require things like encryption to obtain confidentiality. And encryption is not available if you just have a signature generation & verification primitive.

Note that signature generation / verification itself is generally a *hybrid cryptosystem* of a symmetric hash and an asymmetrical computational hard problem such as RSA. But that's something different.

> 2. a way of encrypting confidential data

Certainly not. Operations with a private key of the sender cannot be used to obtain confidentiality. For that you need the public key of the receiver.

> 3. a method of sending handwritten signature to digital media

Duh, no.

> 4. allows the receiver of data to prove the source and integrity

Yes, the receiver can verify that the data was signed by the private key of the sender *if* the receiver has obtained and trusts the public key of the key pair.

Comment: Thanks for helping answer this question. I am learning cryptography and trying to understand it. I really appreciate all the help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

4-so digital signature it allows the receiver of data to prove the source and integrity as well as the Message come from right source